# Broken DAG: [/home/airflow/gcs/dags/cdp/xox/cdp_box_audit.py] No module named 'dags.box'

Tags: python, google-cloud-composer

I recently moved to google composer from airflow server,what is the recommended folder structure for *dags*, *sub dags*, *config files* ?

- Error message, getting Broken DAG:

```
[/home/airflow/gcs/dags/cdp/box/cdp_box_audit.py] No module named dags.box
```

- Current structure:

```
    ->dags ->box (note:project name as a folder) cdp_box_audit.py 
    ->dags ->box ->code ->python ->config dags_config.py
```

In the `cdp_box_audit.py` file, I have below line but composer is not able to detect the dags_config file:

```py
from dags.box.code.python.config import dags_config
```

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Composer uses a Cloud Storage bucket that is synchronized with the directories in the Composer nodes:

- The bucket path: gs://bucket-name/dags
- The instance DAG's path: /home/airflow/gcs/dags

What ever is uploaded into the bucket directory will be syncronized with the correlated directories in the nodes. Check '[Folders in the Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#folders_in_the_bucket)' for reviewing other folders.

To install a local python dependency, you needs to create a specific structure inside the bucket that will be recreated in the workers. There is an example in [here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/using/installing-python-dependencies#install-local) to upload a depenndency as follows:

```
dags/
  use_local_deps.py  
  dependencies/
    __init__.py
    coin_module.py
```

so that you can use the module as in:

```
from dependencies import coin_module
```

In your case, I think you can try:

```
dags/
  cdp_box_audit.py  # A DAG file.
  dags/
    box/
      code/
        python/
          config/
            __init__.py
            dags_config.py
```

I'm not a python expert, but afaik, __init__.py is needed.